# Cholesky decomposition in eigen c++: how to get both the D vector and the inverse in one swoop?

Tags: c++, eigen

A quick (maybe naive) question. Consider the following code, where `Sig` is a  symmetric PSD matrix.

```
VectorXf c=Sig.ldlt().vectorD();
int p=Sig.cols();
MatrixXf b=MatrixXf::Identity(p,p); 
Sig.ldlt().solveInPlace(b);
```

How many times is the Cholesky factorization of `Sig` performed here?
If the answer to the above is more than once, I need both the D vector 
and the inverse of `Sig`. What's the fastest way (e.g. without redundant 
coputations) to get both in eigen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two cholesky decompositions, one for each `ldlt()` call. The `ldlt()` function returns an [LDLT](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1LDLT.html) object. From that you can get all the matrices involved in the Cholesky decomposition.

```
LDLT<MatrixXf> chol = Sig.ldlt();
VectorXf c = chol.vectorD();
int p = Sig.cols();
MatrixXf b = MatrixXf::Identity(p, p);
b = chol.solve(b);
```

Comment: @user189035 Eigen will automatically solve it in place when the assigned value and parameter are the same, see [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1LDLT.html#a71f78ede18adb53bdfe988161653e812)